# how to measure time between two button clicks in java

Tags: java

I am doing an employee clocking system and payroll processing. I am having problems in clocking the employees. I have managed to create a clock but the problem is that I want to start the clock when a 'clock in' button is pressed and stop the clock when a 'clock out' button is pressed and store the total time worked in a database.

Comment: What do you mean by "managed to create a clock"? We have no idea what kind of application this is. Usually you measure time in Java using `System.nanoTime`, calling it once on a start event and once on a stop event...

Comment: is there anything at all that you already tried to solve this issue? It is typically appreciated if you show you own efforts, the error messages you get (if any), etc. If possible it is good if you show a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as this makes it easiest for others to help you

Answer (score 1):

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
yourAction();
long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long time = endTime - startTime;
```

Answer (score 0):

Draw a UI for a clock. When you start click a button start a handler to start update the UI of a clock and do the same thing for another stop button also.

Because when you are trying to update an UI from child thread it will thrown an exception.

Make use of System.currentTimemilli() api to calculate the time.